# Issues Converting jQuery and CSS3 Scrolling Effect from Functional Vertical to Desired Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, stroll.js

I have been playing around with stroll.js today (http://lab.hakim.se/scroll-effects/)
I am new to jQuery, but i'm trying to learn the language to improve my webdesign. I put a lot of effort in this question to make sure I didn't miss anything I did not know yet. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**stroll.js is built for vertical scrolling** http://jsfiddle.net/WtCj8/7/ (see this example)
My goal is to **convert** the jQuery so the plugin works for **horizontal scrolling**. This would give a lot of new design options and new freedom.

**I have taken the following steps** to accomplish this:
In horizontal scrolling the 'top' of the page is the left side and the bottom is the right side. The Height is not important but the Width is.

```
offsetHeight > offsetWidth
offsetTop    > offsetLeft
offsetBottom > offsetRight
```

I have converted the HTML/CSS so the objects are oriented as a Horizontal List. 
I have adjusted the jQuery according to my theory to make it functional. (I kept close my working example (the first jsfiddle link))

My changes resulted in the following jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/WtCj8/8/
The fiddle is not functional like my first example. The jQuery does not name past/future cells like it does in my first example. **My Question is why does it not work and how do I solve it /  in what direction do I have to look for a solution?**

The most important rules for this question are: 164 -242 in the jsFiddle these are the rules i made changes in to achieve the desired effect.

Thanks a million for any help! I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a simple modification on js line 291 http://jsfiddle.net/WtCj8/10/

```
function updateHeight() {
    list.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
    stroll.bind('ul');
}
```

Also some tunes on the css (setting word-wrap and width auto for the UL)

Comment: good to see it working! thanks a lot. The changes to the CSS are for the better too. You made my day.